# Why don't hear music after recording (Swift 2.3)

Tags: avplayer, xcode8, ios10, avaudiorecorder, swift2

I make a karaoke application. If headphone doesn't plugin app works fine.(my voice and background music record together). it is successful. but I'm the same way with headphone Then I listen to the recording. I can not hear the background music.But I hear the voice clearly.I attached the code below I used:

https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but it might be the same issue here: [How can I record the audio output of the iPhone? (like sounds of my app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165894/how-can-i-record-the-audio-output-of-the-iphone-like-sounds-of-my-app)

It seems like you can't record the audio your own app plays using AVFoundation, but have to use CoreAudio to get the low level audio signal. Maybe that helps? :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.can you help me to find the iTunes music library path?I want to send the selected song in iTunes to  PHP server.

Comment: can anyone give me a code for simultaneous record and playback using headphone as well as default speaker

Comment: Is there any other way to hear music and voice clearly at perfect sound while using a headphone?